# how does openssl smime determine micalg parameter?

Tags: ruby, openssl, smime

When I build a signed S/MIME message using `openssl smime -sign`, how does openssl determine what value to use for the `micalg` parameter? (ie: `micalg="sha-256"` in my example below...) I can see this value in the S/MIME text and in the ASN of the generated signature, but I can't figure out where it's coming from or how I could change it.

I am using the ruby openssl wrapper library. When I create a PKCS7 document, I want to inspect it to determine the correct value to use for `micalg` (when I send an AS2 MDN back to a client)...

```rb
pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign certificate, pkey, message
pkcs7.detached = true
```

I'm trying to understand how to inspect `pkcs7` here to determine the `micalg` I should use when constructing a `Content-Type` header like `openssl smime -sign` does.

I first thought this was somehow derived from the certificate and/or key I used to sign the message, but I still see `micalg="sha-256"` even when I generate a certificate using another algorithm like `md5`.

Here are sample commands using openssl cli tool, since I'm guessing that's familiar to more folks here than the ruby wrapper. (It's a very thin wrapper, so translating between the two is usually straightforward.)

```
-> % openssl req -x509 -md5 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server_md5.key -out server_md5.crt -days 365

-> % openssl smime -sign -text -in message.txt -signer test/certificates/server_md5.crt -inkey test/certificates/server_md5.key

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----FA974EDD77D0E708FEB7C0F3E6B14F13"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------FA974EDD77D0E708FEB7C0F3E6B14F13
Content-Type: text/plain

this is the content of message.txt

------FA974EDD77D0E708FEB7C0F3E6B14F13
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIFhgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIFdzCCBXMCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkq
... signature removed for length ...
ppMlHw6KISLkBtFChJvSx5EyeeyN6cMfiXs=

------FA974EDD77D0E708FEB7C0F3E6B14F13--
```

If i save the generated signature into a separate file & inspect it, i think i see the data i'm interested in in in the `d.sign > md_algs` portion of the raw ASN1.

```
openssl pkcs7 -in signature.p7m -print
PKCS7: 
  type: pkcs7-signedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
  d.sign: 
    version: 1
    md_algs:
        algorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)
        parameter: NULL
    contents: 
      type: pkcs7-data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)
      d.data: <ABSENT>
```

`d.sign > md_algs` seems to correspond with the following from the S/MIME RFC

> digestAlgorithms is a collection of message-digest algorithm
> identifiers. There may be any number of elements in the collection,
> including zero. Each element identifies the message-digest algorithm
> (and any associated parameters) under which the content is digested
> for a some signer. The collection is intended to list the
> message-digest algorithms employed by all of the signers, in any
> order, to facilitate one-pass signature verification.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-9.1

I just can't determine how to either

1. specify this value when I sign the message
2. or how to inspect the generated signature to determine the micalg